# cascading the dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

**this is jquery function-
now i am able to pass the city name and save it to database but how to change locality with change in city name. i am zero at jquery.Unable to understand this line  $.getJSON(localityUrl, { ID: $(this).val() }, function (data) { plzzz suggest me some changes to be made--**

```
     <script type="text/javascript">        
      $(document).ready(function () {
        var localityUrl = '@Url.Action("FetchLocalities")';
        var localities = $('#SelectedLocality');
          $('#SelectedCity').change(function () {  localities.empty();
            subLocalities.empty();
            $.getJSON(localityUrl, { ID: $(this).val() }, function (data) {
                if (!data) {
                    return;
                }
                localities.append($('<option></option>').val('').text('Please select'));
                $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                     localities.append($('<option></option>').val(item.Value).text(item.Text));
                   // localities.append($('<option data-lat=' + item.Latitude + ' data-lng=' + item.Longitude + '></option>').text(item.Text));
                });
            });
        })
```

**and my city drop down is like this ---------**

```
       <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SelectedCity)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <select id="SelectedCity" name="SelectedCity">
                @foreach (var thisCity in Model.CityList)
                {
                    <option value="@thisCity.Name" data-lat="@thisCity.Latitude" data-long="@thisCity.Longitude" data-name="@thisCity.Name" >@thisCity.Name</option>
                }
            </select>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SelectedCity)
    </div>
```

**and my cities in the service layer are like this---**

```
    public List<City> FetchCities()
      {
       List<City> cities = new List<City>();
       cities.Add(new City() { Id = 1, Name = "--Select Your City--", Latitude = 28.6139M, Longitude = 77.2090M });
       cities.Add(new City() { Id = 2, Name = "Faridabaad", Latitude = 28.4211M, Longitude = 77.3078M });
       return cities;
   }
```

**and my localities are like this---**

```
     public List<Locality> FetchLocalities()
      {
       List<Locality> localities = new List<Locality>();
       localities.Add(new Locality() { Id = 1, CityName = "Faridabaad", Name = "East Faridabaad" });
       localities.Add(new Locality() { Id = 2, CityName = "Faridabaad", Name = "West Faridabaad" });
        return localities;
    }
```

**now my controller is something like this to fetch localities--**

```
        public JsonResult FetchLocalities(string name)
         {
           var data = _localityService.FetchLocalities()
            //.Where(l => l.CityId == Id)
            .Where(l => l.CityName == name)
            .Select(l => new { Value = l.CityName, Text = l.Name });
        return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`localityUrl` is the url your calling- in your case it would be `var localityUrl = '@Url.Action("FetchLocalities", "yourControllerName")';`

`{ ID: $(this).val() }` is the data your passing to the controller, in your case it needs to be `{ name: $(this).val() }` because your method has parameter `string name` (not ID) and `$(this).val()` equates to the value of the selected option

and `data` in `function (data)` is the data your returning back from the controller method, in your case a collection of objects containing 2 properties, `Value` and `Text`

Comment: i want to kneel in front of u sir.U r simply genius. but still i cant understand from where this ID parameter i was sending before and now name parameter. there was no capitalized ID parameter in my whole code. From where it was coming in $.getJson(). before i was fetching localities then in select option of dropdown it was like this <option value="@thisCity.Id not capita;ized ID.how things were working. PLzz suggest me some reference material on this. thxx once again @Stephen Muecke

Comment: The `ID` in `{ ID: $(this).val() }` denotes the name of the name/value pair your sending to the controller. You could leave it as `ID` and change you method to `public JsonResult FetchLocalities(string ID)` for example. Or it could be ``{ name: $(this).val(), something: 'someValue }` and the method would be `public JsonResult FetchLocalities(string name, string something)`

Comment: Best reference is the [jquery api site](http://api.jquery.com/). It documents all the functions with good examples, for example the [$.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) method

Comment: how to configureViewModel() method should be changed to make locality property from selectList LocalityList{get;set;} to List<Locality> LocalityList {get; set:} Currently its showing Error : cannot implicitly convert type '....MVC.SelectList' to System.collections.Generic.List the configure view model is here---pastebin.com/hAy8uEWk

Comment: @AshishSrivastava, You should really be asking a new question (and you have not given enough detail), but best guess is   `public List<Locality> LocalityList { get; set: }` needs to be `public SelectList LocalityList { get; set: }`

Comment: I wanna use pure html control instead of dropdownlistFor() of mvc.If i choose that then what should i change here model.LocalityList = new SelectList(localities, "CityName", "Name"); complete code is here ---http://pastebin.com/0Uipe12S

Comment: Sorry, but you need to ask a new question (none of this relates to your question). But why on earth would you want to use 'pure html' (by which I assume you don't want do use the html helpers - which equates to _I don't want to it correctly_). You wont get proper 2-way model binding, or built-in client side validation, and you will be writing more code that will be more difficult to test and debug.

Comment: okkk sir thnxx @Stephen Muecke for ur reply Actually i was unable to figure out why my sublocality drop down is not working. Its not fetching anything on change of locality name the complete code is here---http://pastebin.com/vKERGxzr

Comment: You have not shown the controller method for `FetchSubLocalities(string name)` so impossible to tell (ask a new question and I or someone else will be able to help you out)

Comment: [HttpGet]
        public JsonResult FetchSubLocalities(string name)
        {
            //int localityID = Repository.FetchLocalities().Where(l => l.ID == ID).Select(l => l.LocalityID).First();
            var data = _sublocalityService.FetchSubLocalities()
                //.Where(l => l.LocalityId == Id)
                .Where(l => l.LocalityName == name)
                .Select(l => new { Value = l.LocalityName, Text = l.Name });
            return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

Comment: @AshishSrivastava, YOU HAVE TO ASK A NEW QUESTION! (in any case, here is the [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/GTYuJV) showing that it does work)

Comment: okk sir dont go away i will ask it in a new question with complete detail just give me 10 min @Stephen Muecke

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using $.getJSON() you can make an ajax call to your controller action and reload all the localities separately by passing the desired parameter.

Comment: Which is exactly what `$.getJSON()` does!

Comment: $.getJSON() is a short hand notation for $.ajax() with Json as a result. $.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success
});